# EPPlus error after image added, Value cannot be null, Parameter name: contentType

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have created an excel file using `EPPlus` and everything is OK until I try to add an image to my worksheet and I receive the error

> (Value cannot be null, Parameter name: contentType)

in the following line:

```
package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("MasterPackingList", createPackingListExcel(dt));
```

When below code part is removed, it works

```
System.Drawing.Image logo = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Images/")+"PLLogo_Nestle.png");
var addedLogo = worksheet.Drawings.AddPicture("Logo", logo);
```

Below is how I provide the excel to users:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=file.xlsx");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());
Response.End();
```

Comment: The way you've added image is fine. I wonder in which statement the exception was thrown?

Comment: I have found a fix, but not the reason behind the error. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct but when worksheet is returned by a method (createPackingListExcel in my case) this misterious error occurs.

So instead of returning the worksheet, I send my package to the function as parameter and let the worksheet to be added to the package within the function createPackingListExcel, then error is gone. Interesting...

Comment: Found the same issue, thanks for the hint. Rather than ever returning a worksheet or package, best to pass it as a parameter in the function.